# Creating an async tcp server using go language

Tags: go

I want to start a server which listens on a specific port and does some calculations async and returns a result. 
Any leads on the same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use google for things like this before you go ahead and start a question.

Anyways you can find an example here.
https://gist.github.com/iwanbk/2295255